# Hay alguna forma de que no se inicialice mi componte hijo al cargar el padre en Angular 8?

Tags: angular

Estoy teniendo un problema cuando ingreso al formulario que seria el componente padre este automáticamente carga los métodos que tiene el componente hijo en el `OnInit`, esto agrega un poco mas de carga a mi componente padre

Hay alguna forma de que mi componente hijo se incialice cuando le de `click` a un botón o de otra forma ?

Dentro del html de mi padre tengo el hijo de esta forma

```
<app-solicitud-servicios #solicitud1></app-solicitud-servicios>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el ngIf y asociarlo a una condición controlada en el padre, cuando la condición se cumpla se cargará el componente hijo
`<app-solicitud-servicios #solicitud1 *ngIf="condicion"></app-solicitud-servicios>`

Comment: Voy a probar si en ngIf inhabilita la carga del Oninit del hijo y te cuento

Comment: funciona la solución pero tengo un inconveniente, al momento de ejecutar un método que no esta dentro del `onInit` me genera un error me dice que el método no esta definido, a que se debe ??

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'abrirSolicitud' of undefined` Este es el error que me aparece

Comment: Tengo que ver el código para entender. Puedes crear un gist en github de esos dos componentes para poder ayudarte.